# Opposite of a sentinel value

Tags: c, error-handling, sentinel

I need to indicate an error value that is encapsulated in a string. For example, here would be an example:

```
int a = "asd";
==> '\x00asd'
// meaning an error was generated and the original value
// that generated it was 'asd'
```

Where `\x00` at the start would indicate that the value to follow is actually an error. Is there a term for this type of "sentinel-value" at the start of a string?

Comment: "error value that is encapsulated in a string." --> The _string_ ends with the fist _null character_.  Looks like you want to hide info _after_ the string.

Comment: @chux perhaps could use `\x01` instead then? Basically, any rare character that we can show "what follows is an error value".

Comment: What if the original string begins with `"\x01"`?  Something has to give up general string usage.  I think you are looking for an "out-of-band" character or escape character.  To meet your goal, perhaps post the higher level usage to add clarity.

Comment: `int a = "asd"`... what?